# Href not working within Javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have got this code below and I want to know how I can add a clickable link to the boxes under each title.

I want this `<a href=" . '"callto://+' . $getTelephone . '"' . ">Call on Skype</a>` to appear in the first box. But I cannot get it to work as the whole function just stops working when I add it.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.environment_service_packages = 
    [
      {name: 'obj1', info: {text: '<?php echo "A html link below \\n\\n Call on Skype"; ?>', show: true}},
      {name: 'obj2', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj2', show: true}},
      {name: 'obj3', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj3', show: true}},
      {name: 'obj4', info: {text: 'some extra info for obj4', show: false}},
    ];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
  <table ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr class="info">
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="x in environment_service_packages">
      <tr ng-click="x.info.show = !x.info.show">
        <td> {{ x.name }}
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="x.info.show">
        <td>
          <pre>{{ x.info.text }}</pre>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting ng-repeat on the tbody will create a body for every member in the array.

Try putting ng-repeat-start on the first row and ng-repeat-end on the second row.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this

Answer (score 0):

You can't run PHP code in client side...
you need to change HTML to something like:

```
<a href="callto://{{this.come.from.angular.getTelephone }}">Call on Skype</a>
```

Comment: I am not running the code client side, it is on a live website.

Comment: way you have <?php echo ?

Comment: as i can understand, you make AngularJS app right?
so, data is probably coming from PHP cos you have line as:{name: 'obj1', info: {text: '<?php echo

Comment: it simple, if you need link to phone, just send phone no from the server and then use the code sample i write to render the proper link

Comment: At the moment, I am using php to echo all of the text including the variables and it all works fine, but my problem is making the hyperlinks.

Comment: Also, the telephone number comes from a database.

Comment: ok, great, then you just use standard Angular output in the HTML using {{}} notation.

Comment: How do I set an Angular output to a php variable?

Comment: hm... question is to generic, so i will answer what i do:
normally my PHP is only on server side and i communicate from Angular with HTTP post/get etc.... no direct communications = everything most be output as JSON 
i will assume you are outputting while html with angular in it... so best answer will be to put global variable from PHP in JavaScript and then use it in Angular as native JS

Comment: I mean, how do I set {{Telephone}} to $getTelephone?